# Error message in command line when trying to convert font-awesome to PNG

Tags: python, command-line, terminal, font-awesome

I'm trying to get font-awesome PNGs via https://github.com/odyniec/font-awesome-to-png. I have downloaded the TTF file and entered `font-awesome-to-png.py ALL` in the command line. But it gives me this error:

`-bash: font-awesome-to-png.py: command not found` I'm running on Mac OS X Maveriks.

Can anybody help me figure out why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: `python font-awesome-to-png.py`

Comment: I tried that and this is the new error it gives me. "python: can't open file 'font-awesome-to-png.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: You don't have the file `font-awesome-to-png.py` in the working directory. Go to the directory where the file is and run it.

Comment: So the folder which has the TFF file, I cloned from GitHub is called "Font-Awesome". I'm in that folder and ran the code. Should I be in "Gemfile"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link http://fa2png.io/ ,

which convert all font-awesome icons to png images of required size and color